# Better solution to using many "OR LIKE" operators in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a large database from which I am trying to get data containing certain keywords. Currently, I am using many "OR LIKE %keyword%" after each other but this seems to be very slow.
Is there a better alternative to using this?

Comment: The only possible alternative is full-text searching.

Comment: `LIKE %keyword%` is always slow, since it can't use an index.